# Conversion of datatype Varchar to date in an existing column

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I've read similar articles here in Stackoverflow, but i can't seem to make it work in my case.

I have column named (Date), with data type varchar, and the data throughout the whole column looks like this (1999-12-31-23-00-01) without parenthesis.

So, instead of Varchar, I want the same value, but in datetime format.

This is my table structure:

CREATE TABLE App
(

[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

[Date] Varchar(50) NULL,

[Inst.nr] [smallint] NULL,

[Creator Initials] varchar NULL,

[AppOwner] varchar NULL,

[Status] varchar NULL,

[Serial.Nr] varchar NULL,

[MAC.Addr] varchar NULL,

[Dell.nr] varchar NULL,

[Model] varchar NULL,

[Description] varchar NULL,

[Service Warranty] [date] NULL,

[Purchased] [date] NULL,
)

Actually, the problem is not with the structure, its some old data from an Excel file, which was imported into SQL database. 
In my [Date] column, which is in Varchar right now, The data inside this column looks like this 1999-12-31-23-00-01

As you can see, it looks like a datetime format, but it won't accept the conversion from varchar to datetime

Comment: "SAME output" means: in a query?

Comment: Think you ask for the conversion to datetime?

Comment: smalldatetime is the datatype you need to achieve it. NOT DATETIME Datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CONVERT` function in Sql Server, convert to datetime follow format type `120`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING('(1999-12-31-23-00-01)',2,10) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING('(1999-12-31-23-00-01)',13,8),'-',':'),120)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Hello Giau,
Your code gave me the same results as Eric's code. it creates a new column in a random table. can you please tell me how to convert the whole column in my table
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi Kalash, give me your table structure

Comment: Without parenthesis '1999-12-31-23-00-01':

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING([Date],1,10) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Date],12,8),'-',':'),120)
as DateResult
from App

Comment: I've got an error
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: try this: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING([Date],2,10) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Date],13,8),'-',':'),120) as DateResult from App

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you for your effort, but 
I've got this error

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: check your data in table App, all rows with column [Date] must be  'yyyy-mm-dd-hh-MM-ss' and not be null or length not equals 19

Comment: try this :SELECT CASE WHEN [Date] is null then null WHEN LEN([Date]) <> 19 then null else CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING([Date],2,10) + ' ' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Date],13,8),'-',':'),120) end as DateResult from App

Comment: I've dobble checked the column, which have 4482 rows, and they all look alike. Is there a way to send you the file? i've been fighting this for weeks.
If there is no solution for this, is there a way to tell SQL to keep the data as they are, but all new input in the same column should be in datetime format?

Comment: I've got the same error again: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: send me your data via mail: htangiau12th01@gmail.com or dev.giauht@gmail.com

Comment: did you recieve my mail?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are asking the conversion to datetime

```
SELECT 
  -- Convert using ISO date time yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
  CONVERT(datetime, 
          LEFT(Date, 10) + ' ' + 
          REPLACE(RIGHT(Date, 8), '-', ':')
         ) AS DateInDatetime
FROM
  (VALUES 
    -- assume format in yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss
    ('1999-12-31-23-00-01') 
  ) t (Date)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/2276)

Comment: Hello Eric,
i ran your command, it creates a new column in a random table. how to execute it in my table which is called app. 
Oh and yes, I want it converted to datetime :)
Thank you in advance